# Diamond question mark in text after migrating content

Tags: custom-field, database, meta-query

I have a weird issue with the diamond question marks for strange symbols in Wordpress. I just migrated my website and content to a new redesigned template. 
[You can see at the bottom of this url what my issue is](https://mvoconsultants.nl/diensten/mvo-nulmeting/).

It looks like the diamond is only appearing instead of a space **before** a html tag. So in the bottom of the page you see the issue with an `<a>` tag, but it also happens with for example `<strong>` tags through the website.

- My database is InnoDB with `utf8_general_ci`
- Meta tag: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8"/>`
- Custom template
- Advanced Custom Fields

Anyone who can help out?

Comment: this sign replace something that is missing or it is just add to the initial content ? if it's just add, you can try to clean the database with a tool like this : https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB

Comment: I searched for the text in the database. But there I just see the space, no weird characters or something. So I don't know where to look for with the replace library. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

A diamond question mark is browser for "I can't decode that."

I would assume what is happening is when you migrated the HTML entity for space was encoded in your database wrong or WordPress is reading it with the wrong encoding assumed.

Comment: Yes, I did understand that it was a missing sign or character. Like I mentioned in a comment above; I searched the database, but no weird signs or characters anywhere, just the spaces. Any suggestions on what to change the Wordpress reading to?